# How to get a byte array in c/c++ from a function with unknown return type?

Tags: c++, c, byte, function-pointers, return-type

For example, I know the address of the function (lets say its `0x0183ad0`), and I would like to get an object from that function which returns an unknown type:

```
unknownType(*fname)() = (unknownType(*)())0x0183ad0
```

Is there any global type I can replace `unknownType` with or any method to get that object as a byte array (I know the `sizeof(unknownType)`)

### NOTE:

The function return an object NOT A POINTER

---

### EDIT:

It worked thanks to Botje's answer:
[image: Answer]

Comment: **AN ARRAY IS *NOT* A POINTER**.  An array is a block of memory that actually exists somewhere in memory.  **AN ARRAY HAS AN ADDRESS**.  A pointer is a single integer-type variable that **HOLDS** an address - an address that may or may not be valid.  Your home exists somewhere and you get mail because it has an address.  But if you put some random address on a box and mail it, you have no idea where it's going to go.  If you get the address on the box correct, it gets sent where you want it to go.

Comment: For the future, Amin, [Do not post pictures of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/402169)

Comment: Oh sorry. I will edit it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"byte array" would be `uint8_t*` or `unsigned char*`.

If you know the size of `unknownType` I would create a

```
struct unknownType {
    uint8_t stuff[123];
};
```

so you can adapt the struct definition as you gain better understanding of its fields.

Comment: But an array is a pointer, and pointers would point to another address instead of the object. For your example that array will only take the first 4 bytes in the object (a pointer is 4 bytes long) and the app may crash.

Comment: It depends on what the function actually returns. If it returns a pointer, you will need to cast the address to a function that returns a `unknownType*`. If it returns a struct, my answer will work because the compiler copies field by field (or `memcpy` if it is a POD)

Comment: No if it returns a struct, your answer wont work because an array is a pointer ! It we will store the first four fields as the pointer address and the app will crash !

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. In C++ this will work as described.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove there. `sizeof(t)` = `sizeof(Test*)` = 4 (on your system). `sizeof(*t)` or `sizeof(Test)` will produce the correct 123.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a void function pointer and use that prototype for each of the functions that you have the address of: The return value in this example is to a a RANDOM STRUCTURE it could be the whole array of whatever you want bytes, ints, chars- This could of course be different for each function called, as long as the function signature was the same (you could always add a void pointer on the parameter list if they need different input)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _RANDSTRUCT 
{
    int Num ;
} RANDSTRUCT ;

typedef void * UNKNOWNFUNC (void) ;

UNKNOWNFUNC *myFunc() ;

int main()
{
    void *retP ;
    UNKNOWNFUNC *fnP ;
    
    retP = myFunc () ;

    printf ("Num %d (direct call)\n", ((RANDSTRUCT *)retP)->Num) ;

    fnP = (void *)&myFunc ;
    retP = fnP () ;
    
    printf ("Num %d (fn addr call)\n", ((RANDSTRUCT *)retP)->Num) ;
    
    return 0;
}

UNKNOWNFUNC *myFunc () {
    static RANDSTRUCT randstruct[2] = {100, 200} ;
    
    return ((void *)&randstruct[0]) ;
}
```

Comment: Nope. My problem is that the function returns an object, not a pointer to it.

Comment: Original question said C/C++, this answer is for C, a structure (and pointer to) is the closest you get to an object.

Comment: The identifier `_RANDSTRUCT` is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, the program will have undefined behaviour. You should give another name for the sruct. Or let it be unnamed since you also give it a type name.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get a byte array in c/c++ from a function with unknown return type?

Only way to call a function in C++ is to know its return type. If you don't know the return type, then you cannot call the function, and as such you cannot get the object returned by the function.

> It worked thanks to Botje's answer

It may look like it works, but the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: Why undefined behaviour ? I can test it with caution and the trick is done. I can even access private members with it

Comment: @AminGuermazi `Why undefined behaviour ?` Because the C++ language says that it is. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317751/2079303 `I can test it with caution` I doubt you'll be able to test every execution of that code now and in future. It is not guaranteed to work no matter how many times you test it.