# Is it safe to cast a function pointer accepting pointer type to another function pointer accepting reference type?

Tags: c++, casting, pass-by-reference, function-pointers, dllimport

What are the drawbacks of casting a function pointer that accepts "Pointer parameter" to another function pointer that accepts "Reference parameter"?

consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
int test(int* x)
{
    (*x)*=2;
    return *x;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = test(&a);
    std::cout<<"a="<<a<<" and b="<<b<<"\r\n";
    
    //Type casting:
    int (*test2)(int&) = (int(*)(int&))&test;
    
    int c = 5;
    int d = test2(c);
    std::cout<<"c="<<c<<" and d="<<d<<"\r\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It is useful specially when importing a function from a dynamic linked library (DLL).
For example WriteFile function from Kernel32.dll has a syntax of:

```
BOOL WriteFile(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
  DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

which can be transferred to:

```
BOOL WriteFile(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
  DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  DWORD&       NumberOfBytesWritten,
  OVERLAPPED&  Overlapped
);
```

Comment: The drawback is that this is undefined behavior, that will result [in demons flying out of everyone's noses](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). If it is not desirable to have demons flying out of everyone noses, then undefined behavior should be avoided.

Comment: _"It is useful specially when importing a function from a dynamic linked library (DLL)"_  - Why ? If the function in the DLL expects a pointer, use a pointer. It is the correct way (to avoid UB) and I find it also clearer than masquerading a reference as a pointer.

Comment: Dupe: [Converting between function pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317623/converting-between-function-pointer-types)

Comment: Yes, it's "safe" to cast a function pointer to a different type of function pointer; no, it's not "safe" to use that pointer without casting it back to its original type.

Answer (score 4):

Although reference and pointer arguments may (likely) be implemented with similar internal mechanics, a reference is *not* a pointer (see: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/10871073)) and, as such, using one *in lieu* of the other is undefined behaviour.

Thus, a **significant drawback** of what you're doing in the shown code is that **it produces undefined behaviour**.

Any decent compiler would (or *should*) warn about this. Clang-cl (within Visual Studio) gives:

> warning : cast from 'int (*)(int *)' to 'int (*)(int &)' converts to
> incompatible function type [-Wcast-function-type-strict]

And MSVC gives:

> warning C4191: 'type cast': unsafe conversion from `'int (__cdecl
> *)(int *)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int &)'
>  warning C4191:         Making a function call using the resulting pointer may cause your
> program to fail